# What happens when a reference of an object (with different types) is deleted?

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm kind of confused about how the reference works in the code below.
From what I understand, b is just an alias of d1. So what's the difference between `delete &b` and `delete d1` ?

b is of type Base but still is an alias of type f, so what differentiates them?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base(){
        cout << "Base Constructor Called\n";
    }
    ~Base(){
        cout << "Base Destructor called\n";
    }
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:
    Derived1(){
        cout << "Derived constructor called\n";
    }
    ~Derived1(){
        cout << "Derived destructor called\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived1 *d1 = new Derived1();
    Base &b = *d1;
    delete &b;
}
```

Comment: `Base b = *d1;` creates a *copy* and `delete &b;` invokes *undefined behavior* - you are trying to `delete` an object with automatic storage duration

Comment: And you probably want to read about `virtual` destructors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I meant Base &b = *d1

Comment: Now you still have *undefined behavior*  because the destructor is not `virtual` (as described in the question I linked in my second comment)

Comment: Yes, I know about virtual destructors (in this case I have to declare the destructor of ```Derived1``` virtual). In my case, I want to understand the difference between calling delete &b and delete d1 (especially what happens to  the memory allocated)

Comment: When we call delete &b (is the space allocated for the Base class is deleted and are vtable pointers of both the Base class and derived1 also deleted? )

Comment: You're fixating on implementation details that may or may not be in play, particularly given the undefined behaviour. I recommend not doing that.

Answer (score 2):

They are differentiated by type.

- `b` refers to an object of type `Base`.
- `d1` points to an object of type `Derived1`.

Those are related, but distinct types.

Your object is a `Derived1`, not just a `Base`. This matters to `delete`. Make your destructors virtual and you'll get away with it, because [that's how polymorphism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors). Otherwise, you have undefined behaviour and there is no meaning to your program.

Comment: From what I understand d1 is a pointer to an object that contains a Base class object and a vtable pointer (if we have also virtual functions). And b will contain nothing or only vtable pointer (if we have also virtual functions). So what happens when we delete &m?

Comment: @Sydney.Ka I already told you. There is no meaning to your program, and thus no answer to that question.

Comment: Sorry I meant &b. I really want to understand what happens to the memory allocated . I already know about virtual constructors but I still don't know what happens to the memory allocated

Comment: Repeating the same question over and over again won't change the answer.

Comment: I didn't repeat it

Comment: You have asked three times what happens when you `delete &b`, and received the same response each time. The answer is _undefined_. _There is no answer_. I can't do anything about that, sorry.

Comment: Yes because I want to understand what happens in memory and not the behavior of the program. Sorry If I wasn't clear!

Comment: What happens in memory is decided by the behaviour of the program. If there is no defined behaviour, it is impossible to predict what "happens in memory". I give up now - I recommend reading more about undefined behaviour and its consequences. It's not just a flag set on your source code; it's an actual thing that you need to seriously take into account. Good luck.